# Configure VSCode Python Interpreter when in a Veracrypt drive

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, veracrypt

I'm trying to get VSCode to recognize my python interpreter within a Veracrypt mounted drive but it won't work. Tried configuring `python.pythonPath` in `settings.json`, tried reinstalling virtual environment no luck. It only sees local versions of python.

Works fine when my project is on my local drive. Anyone have any luck with this?

[image: Tried putting it in settings.json]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIsND.png)

this is my settings

```
"python.venvPath": "/Users/whitek/workspace",
"python.venvFolders": [
    "envs",
    ".pyenv",
    ".direnv",
    ".env"
],
```

you just need to specify python's virtual environment folder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but looks like I'm just a moron. I restarted vscode after, rebooted the virtual python env in my terminal and it works now. Also when you start up the virtual environment it takes a couple of seconds for the VSCode status bar to pick up the new python environment.